# Marking packets of Wireguard peers

Tags: linux, iptables, wireguard

I am working with a firewalling system that heavily relies on `fwmark` to
match rules to VPN connections (IPsec so far, but upgrading to WG). AFAICs
Wireguard’s `fwmark` capability only applies to the Wireguard packets, not
the decrypted traffic received from the peer.

However I need to distinguish traffic arriving from different peers over the
same Wireguard device. Short of hacking the kernel, what options are there to
achieve this?

Comment: @A.B: “per IP address with adequate iptables/nftables rules” – The address based apporach gets quite complicated quickly especially when layers of NAT are added. That complexity could be avoided by simply matching peers by their mark.

Comment: “Also you didn't get the role of WireGuard's mark here: it's for outgoing packets. There's nothing about marking incoming. ” – I did get that. That’s what prompted the question in the first place.